# How to make a navigation bar for showing off different weights of a typeface?

Tags: css, scripting, webfonts, typography

So I am trying to make horizontal interactive bar to show off different weights of my font. I have 14 lines showing it off, but don't how to get it down to 1 line and just switch in between different weights.[Screenshot of the final product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvu9l.png)

Answer (score 1):

I made a pure JS code to clone your text elements then increase the font-weight.

You can see it here => https://codepen.io/baessodiego/pen/YzXbqev

Or here

```
var j = 100

for(i=0; i<9; i++){
var p = document.createElement("P");  // Create a <> element
var t = document.createTextNode("Your font here, " + j);  // Create a text
p.id = "font"; // add id to P
p.appendChild(t); // add Text to P
p.style.fontWeight = j; // add Style to P

j += 100 // Increase weight

document.body.appendChild(p);  // append element to other elements
}
```